# How could SUM(column) give incorrect results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have the following simple MySQL query, called from PHP:

```
SELECT foo_id, SUM(number_of_guests)
FROM guests 
WHERE foo_id = $foo_id
GROUP BY foo_id
```

This works fine, except for one $foo_id, which returns about 2.5 times greater than the sum of the number_of_guests field.

What could cause this behavior for only a certain value of $foo_id?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you give some example data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Is there a join in your query that you omitted in your example?

Comment: No, that is the actual query.

Comment: @B Seven: If it's in actual query, I don't see any way it can behave wrong. You are most likely miscalculated number_of_guests manually (some gui tools automatically limit number of rows, so you might have not seen all of them for `SELECT * FROM guests WHERE foo_id = $foo_id`

Comment: As @MarkByers said; Data, or G.O.  Normally I'd be disinclined to believe that the server is behaving badly, although it would help to know what datatype `$foo_id` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there was one row with a large value for number_of_guests. I didn't see in in browsing the data because there are a few hundred rows. It didn't show up when I copied and pasted from HTML page into Excel because that row was missing most of the other columns, and the HTML page has all the columns.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should work. The error is most likely in the *other* method you are using to verify the result.

> Is there a better way to do this?

Yes. Since you are only fetching one group there's no need for your GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT SUM(number_of_guests)
FROM guests 
WHERE foo_id = $foo_id
```